# What is this use of std::map doing?

Tags: c++

Can anyone explain the output I am getting from this simple program using `std::map`. Note that I insert `p` into the map, but not `q` yet it says it found them both, but also says there is only 1 element in the map!

```
#include <map>
#include <iostream>

struct screenPoint {
  float x = 0, y = 0;
  screenPoint(float x_, float y_): x{x_}, y{y_}{}
};

bool operator<(const screenPoint& left, const screenPoint& right){
  return left.x<right.x&&left.y<right.y;
}

std::map<screenPoint, float> positions;

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {

  auto p = screenPoint(1,2);
  auto q = screenPoint(2,1);
  positions.emplace(p,3);

  auto f = positions.find(p);
  auto g = positions.find(q);

  if (f == positions.end()){
    std::cout << "f not found";
  } else {
    std::cout << "f found";
  }

  std::cout << std::endl;

  if (g == positions.end()){
    std::cout << "g not found";
  } else {
    std::cout << "g found";
  }

  std::cout << std::endl;

  std::cout << "number elements: " << positions.size() << "\n";
  return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
f found
g found
number elements: 1
```

Comment: Condition should be `left.x < right.x || left.y < right.y`

Comment: Do the comparisons actually have some meaning for you (in the sense that you really attach meaning to which object is smaller than the other), or is this just a means to use a dictionary?

Comment: @AmiTavory i just want a dictionary; i don't care about ordering

Comment: @JeromeBaldridge See update, then.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is with the way you defined the comparison functor, in this case. The two elements, `p`, and `q`, have the same `x` and `y`, just inverted. 
Your logic checks that the `x` of one is less than that of the other, as well as the `y`s. This can never evaluate to `true`, for these inputs.

Try this snippet:

```
int main()
{
    auto p = screenPoint(1,2);
    auto q = screenPoint(2,1);

   std::cout << std::boolalpha << (p < q) << " " << (q < p) << std::endl;
}
```

It will print out

```
false false
```

So `p` is not less than `q`, and `q` is not less than `p`. As far as the map is concerned, that makes them equivalent.

Comment: I don't see the point of having inexact equality; if the doubles are  not bitwise equal, won't they hash differently? In which case lookup most likely will not work regardless of how equality is written. You need the hash function to obey the same epsilon as equality, and afaik there is no guarantee that std::hash will be written that way.

Comment: thanks for the help; i've posted a related question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39796763/why-is-this-stdmap-key-not-getting-found

Answer (score 3):

In order to use a data type in an `std::map`, it must have a particular ordering called a strict weak ordering (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weak_ordering). This means that the inequality operator (`<`) obeys a very specific set of rules. The operator you specified however is not a weak ordering. In particular, given two `screenPoint`s, `a` and `b` constructed from (1,2) and (2,1) respectively, you will see that it is false both that `a < b` and that `b < a`. In a strict weak ordering, this would be required to imply that `a == b`, which is not true!

Because your inequality operator does not meet the requirement of a strict weak ordering, `map` ends up doing unexpected things. I recommend reading up more details on what this ordering is, and reading/thinking about why map requires it. In the short term, you can redefine your operator as follows:

```
bool operator<(const screenPoint& left, const screenPoint& right){
  if (left.x != right.x) return left.x < right.x;
  else return (left.y < right.y);
}
```

Comment: It needs to be a Strict Weak Ordering, specifically.

Comment: if I don't actually care about ordering, perhaps a map is not the best container? maybe unordered_map? But then I'd have another problem, I'd have to hash my custom struct, right?

Comment: @Jerome Baldridge that is correct, generally if you don't care about in order traversal and you don't need to worry about adversarial input, unordered_map is the standard choice for better perf in typical use case. Hashing your struct is very easy, you can simply hash each coordinate separately and then bitwise xor the result. You'll also need to define equality which is trivial.

Comment: @NirFriedman since my struct's members are floats, equality among floats is not as easy as `==`

Comment: @Jerome Baldridge well, as I noted below, == is trivial, because your hash function will likely depend on bitwise equality anyhow. It does mean though that your points must be exactly equal for lookup to succeed. You have a number of alternatives, either to discretize your space, or to use more sophisticated data structures. Binary search trees do not work so well for two dimensional data if you want to do within epsilon lookups.

Comment: thanks for the help; i've posted a related question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39796763/why-is-this-stdmap-key-not-getting-found

Comment: @JeromeBaldridge Your related question though was already covered by my answer, which gives the correct code for the comparison operator.

Comment: it appears this solution was not enough. is it not the same as using || ? the std::tie solution in the other question fixes it

Comment: My code above is not equivalent to the or operator, and is equivalent to tie. You can work it out with truth tables.

Comment: Std::tie also includes a check for equivalency, this example does not. They are not the same logic. Additionally, the results of this example are the same as using ||, just more verbosely written.

Comment: Looks like the community generally agrees with @johnbakers.  This is equivalent to OR, and is also not the same as using std::tie. see this followup: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39806517/are-these-two-comparison-expressions-identical

Comment: also, as another pointed out, this solution won't even compile, it is missing some parenthesis

Comment: @JeromeBaldridge minor typo results in my solution results in three down votes and removal of acceptance, despite being most thorough answer. Could also just have suggested edit. Not sure why I bothered trying to help you in the answer, or repeatedly in the comments.

Comment: @NirFriedman the typo is not the reason: you made clear logical mistakes, claiming your solution was different than a solution with || and also claiming your solution was the same as the std::tie implementation. Both of these are incorrect.

Comment: @JeromeBaldridge Yes, there was a minor bug; from the way in which it was written it was pretty obvious what the intent was. Still the most comprehensive answer, and the only person to mention the real fundamental issue: a proper ordering. Understanding the axioms of a strict weak ordering, why they're necessary, and why your ordering did not satisfy it should be your actual take away here. If you understand that, writing the new comparison operator is trivial anyway, and if you don't then you haven't learned what actually matters.

Comment: @NirFriedman it's rather rude for you to suggest I am missing the forest for the trees when your comments indicated you don't know the difference between an `if` and an `or ||`. you should learn the language basics before you tell others they don't know what they are talking about

Comment: @JeromeBaldridge Apparently, wrote a minor bug == don't know the difference. It's pretty obvious from my answer that I know the language quite well, given I was able to answer your question immediately, and (unlike a couple of others on this thread) immediately understood the issues involved with epsilon equality comparison in the context of a hash table. But hey, if it helps you to believe that I know the requirements for map and details of how hashing works, but not how `if` and `||` behave, then as I wrote before: as you please.