# Why is this std::map key not getting found?

Tags: c++

I asked a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39690503/what-is-this-use-of-stdmap-doing) once before and now I have a related problem. Below, the output is "not found" and the number of elements printed is 2.

The line `positions.emplace(r,q);` clearly inserts the element and the map size is correct, so why is `r` not found? `p` *is* found (not logged in this example).

```
#include <map>
#include <iostream>

struct screenPoint {
  float x = 0, y = 0;
  screenPoint(float x_, float y_): x{x_}, y{y_}{}
};

bool operator<(const screenPoint& left, const screenPoint& right){
  return left.x<right.x||left.y<right.y;
}

std::map<screenPoint, screenPoint> positions;

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {

  auto p = screenPoint(593,271.5);
  auto q = screenPoint(595.5,269.5);
  auto r = screenPoint(599,267);
  positions.emplace(p,q);
  positions.emplace(r,q);

  auto f = positions.find(r);

  if (f == positions.end()){
    std::cout << "not found";
  } else {
    std::cout << "found";
  }

  std::cout << std::endl;

  std::cout << "number elements: " << positions.size() << "\n";
  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your comparison operator

```
bool operator<(const screenPoint& left, const screenPoint& right){
  return left.x<right.x||left.y<right.y;
}
```

Is incorrect.  You need to use an if statement and if the `x`'s are equal return if `left.y` is less than `right.y` otherwise return `left.x < right.x`. or use `std::tie` like

```
bool operator<(const screenPoint& left, const screenPoint& right){
  return std::tie(left.x, left.y) < std::tie(right.x, right.y);
}
```

Comment: In my other question, I was using && and it also did not work. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39690503/what-is-this-use-of-stdmap-doing

Comment: @JeromeBaldridge Updated.  Since there is two members it gets more complicated.

Comment: since tie just creates a tuple of references, does this resulting tuple automatically create a good operator< somehow?

Comment: @JeromeBaldridge Yes.  It uses the `operator <` of each member of the tuple and does it in a way where if two members are equal it moves to the next member.  I would suggest you change from `float` to some sort of integer type as well for representing position.  It makes the math easier(no epsilon to deal with) and you really cannot have a fraction of a pixel.

Comment: well, touch points in iOS are given in pixel coordinates as floats and many are indeed fractional.

Comment: this solution with tie seems to work and is the most elegant, so i accept thanks!

Comment: @JeromeBaldridge No problem.  Glad to help

Answer (score 3):

Your `operator<` is not a Strict Weak Ordering.  You have for example both `p<q` and `q<p`.  This means Undefined Behavior for any `map` operations.

One way to provide a valid `operator<`, ignoring NaNs, would be:

```
bool operator<(const screenPoint& left, const screenPoint& right) {
    return left.x < right.x ||
           ( left.x == right.x && left.y < right.y );
}
```

Comment: it would appear the solutions provided in my other question were not sufficient. how can i provide a good operator< for such a simple data structure?

Comment: == is not a good solution if I am using floats. This was mentioned in my linked other question also.

Comment: @krzaq if std::tie merely creates a tuple, does the standard somehow automatically implement this operator< for tuples?

Comment: I would use only `operator<`, like `if( left.x < right.x ) return true; if( right.x < left.x ) return false; return left.y < right.y;` if have to implement it. But better use `std::tie()`

Comment: Putting these in a `std::map` implicitly depends on equality of two floats anyway.  The `operator<` for `std::tuple`s acts equivalently to my example.