# Are these two comparison expressions identical?

Tags: c++

There seems to be some [disagreement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39690503/what-is-this-use-of-stdmap-doing#comment66891972_39690577) in another question about whether these two functions have identical logic:

```
bool operator<(const screenPoint& left, const screenPoint& right){
  if (left.x < right.x) return true;
  else return left.y < right.y;
}

bool operator<(const screenPoint& left, const screenPoint& right){
  return left.x < right.x || left.y < right.y;
}
```

I have stared at these for quite a while and I cannot see how they would behave differently. In both, if `left.x < right.x`, they both return `true`. If not, then they both return the result of `left.y < right.y`. Right?

If not, can someone please elaborate.

Also, it was suggested that the first of these is identical to the implementation of lexographical ordering in `std::tie`, is that true?

Comment: someone has their parentheses all messed up.

Comment: what if they are the same size? then the result would go to else, and it would be incorrect, as they are not of different sizes

Comment: The first one is not identical to `std::tie`, which implements a lexicographical comparison. `std::tie` would always return false if If `left.x` is greater than `right.x`.

Comment: @Charlie the behavior is still the same between the two, right? in both, if left.x == right.x, they both move to the next comparison; after the else or after the OR, the same, no?

Comment: @MikeNakis what's wrong with the parens?

Comment: the two are not only identical, they should even produce the exact same machine code.   The only difference between the two is that the author of the first is of the `return else return` persuasion, which is an abomination and they should burn in hell.

Comment: @JeromeBaldridge well, last time I programmed in C++, (it has been a while,) one was required to put the expression after `if` in parentheses.  Also, I consider it bad form to use  `return` with parentheses.

Comment: @MikeNakis ah you are correct, I didn't even see that.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The two are identical to each other (if you fix the missing parenthesis in the first `if`), but they do not implement a strict weak ordering, so you probably don't want to use them (it would be invalid to use them in standard ordered containers and algorithms).

Proof: Consider the original relation for a=(1,3) b=(2,2). Then a < b and b < a. (asymmetric property violated)

A correct lexicographical ordering would look like this:

```
bool operator<(const screenPoint& left, const screenPoint& right){
    if (left.x < right.x) 
        return true;
    if (left.x > right.x)
        return false;
    return left.y < right.y;
}
```

If your members have only a `<` operator and not a `>` operator, replace `left.x > right.x` by `!(right.x < left.x)`. This is how lexicographical comparison is implemented by `std::pair` and `std::tuple` (which is returned by `std::tie`).

Answer (score 2):

Don't just guess, take your compiler and make it emit asm code to check differences. My compiler (clang) yields the same result for the two versions:

```
#include <tuple>

__attribute__((noinline)) bool operatorLess1(const screenPoint& left, const screenPoint& right)
{
  if (left.x < right.x) return true;
  else return (left.y < right.y);
}

__attribute__((noinline)) bool operatorLess2(const screenPoint& left, const screenPoint& right) 
{
  return left.x < right.x || left.y < right.y;
}

__attribute__((noinline)) bool operatorLess3(const screenPoint& left, const screenPoint& right) 
{
  return std::tie(left.x, left.y) < std::tie(right.x, right.y);
}

__attribute__((noinline)) bool operatorLess4(const screenPoint& left, const screenPoint& right)
{
  if (left.x < right.x) return true;
  else if (left.x > right.x) return false;
  else return (left.y < right.y);
}
```

compiled with

```
clang++ -S -masm=intel -std=c++11 -O2 a.cpp
```

yields:

```
__Z13operatorLess1RK11screenPointS1_:   ## @_Z13operatorLess1RK11screenPointS1_
    push    rbp
    mov rbp, rsp
Ltmp2:
    movss   xmm0, dword ptr [rsi]   ## xmm0 = mem[0],zero,zero,zero
    mov al, 1
    ucomiss xmm0, dword ptr [rdi]
    ja  LBB0_2
    movss   xmm0, dword ptr [rsi + 4] ## xmm0 = mem[0],zero,zero,zero
    ucomiss xmm0, dword ptr [rdi + 4]
    seta    al
LBB0_2:
    pop rbp
    ret
    .cfi_endproc


__Z13operatorLess2RK11screenPointS1_:   ## @_Z13operatorLess2RK11screenPointS1_
    .cfi_startproc
    push    rbp
    mov rbp, rsp
Ltmp5:
    movss   xmm0, dword ptr [rsi]   ## xmm0 = mem[0],zero,zero,zero
    mov al, 1
    ucomiss xmm0, dword ptr [rdi]
    ja  LBB1_2
    movss   xmm0, dword ptr [rsi + 4] ## xmm0 = mem[0],zero,zero,zero
    ucomiss xmm0, dword ptr [rdi + 4]
    seta    al
LBB1_2:
    pop rbp
    ret
    .cfi_endproc


__Z13operatorLess3RK11screenPointS1_:   ## @_Z13operatorLess3RK11screenPointS1_
    push    rbp
    mov rbp, rsp
Ltmp8:
    movss   xmm0, dword ptr [rdi]   ## xmm0 = mem[0],zero,zero,zero
    movss   xmm1, dword ptr [rsi]   ## xmm1 = mem[0],zero,zero,zero
    mov al, 1
    ucomiss xmm1, xmm0
    ja  LBB2_4
    ucomiss xmm0, xmm1
    jbe LBB2_3
    xor eax, eax
    pop rbp
    ret
LBB2_3:
    movss   xmm0, dword ptr [rsi + 4] ## xmm0 = mem[0],zero,zero,zero
    ucomiss xmm0, dword ptr [rdi + 4]
    seta    al
LBB2_4:                                 ## %_ZNSt3__1ltIJRKfS2_EJS2_S2_EEEbRKNS_5tupleIJDpT_EEERKNS3_IJDpT0_EEE.exit
    pop rbp
    ret
    .cfi_endproc

__Z13operatorLess4RK11screenPointS1_:   ## @_Z13operatorLess4RK11screenPointS1_
    .cfi_startproc
    push    rbp
    mov rbp, rsp
Ltmp11:
    movss   xmm0, dword ptr [rdi]   ## xmm0 = mem[0],zero,zero,zero
    movss   xmm1, dword ptr [rsi]   ## xmm1 = mem[0],zero,zero,zero
    mov al, 1
    ucomiss xmm1, xmm0
    ja  LBB3_4
    ucomiss xmm0, xmm1
    jbe LBB3_3
    xor eax, eax
    pop rbp
    ret
LBB3_3:
    movss   xmm0, dword ptr [rsi + 4] ## xmm0 = mem[0],zero,zero,zero
    ucomiss xmm0, dword ptr [rdi + 4]
    seta    al
LBB3_4:
    pop rbp
    ret
    .cfi_endproc
```

As you can see the first two versions are the same and they'll compare `x` or directly compare `y`. `std::tie` version instead, as pointed out by interjay, is a complete weak ordering returns 0 when `left.x > left.y`. Indeed its code is the same as `operatorLess4`.

Comment: Re: "Don't just guess, take your compiler and make it emit asm code" -- there is a third possibility, and that's **understand the language rules** so that you know what both code snippets mean.